# How to programmatically change Windows system time?

Tags: windows, time, clock

How is the Windows system clock set programmatically?

I'm working with a Java system on XP, but knowing how to do this generally from C, or the command line, is probably the way to go. I can simply invoke some external process.

What privilege level is required by the program that sets the clock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Win32 API that does this is [`SetSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As the documentation states, it requires that you have the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege.

From the command line it's done with the `TIME` internal command.